# How to make the php codeIgniter active record group?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

First, I have something in my model:

```
    $this->db->where('status', $aStatus);     
    $this->db->limit($aLimit, $aOffset);   

    $this->db->or_like('title', $aString);    
    $this->db->or_like('description', $aString);    

    $this->db->select('id,description,title,fee');

    $query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);
```

And I got this query:

> SELECT `id`, `description`,`title`, `fee` FROM (`events`) WHERE
>   `status` =  0 AND  `title`  LIKE '%space%' OR  `description`  LIKE
>   '%space%' LIMIT 5

But I would like to let it generate this query instead

> SELECT `id`, `description`,`title`, `fee` FROM (`events`) WHERE
>   `status` =  0 AND  ***(***`title`  LIKE '%space%' OR  `description`  LIKE
>   '%space%'***)*** LIMIT 5

How can I modify to do so? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Think the only way you'll manage that is by doing something along the lines of:

```
$this->db->where('status', $aStatus);
$this->db->where("(title LIKE '%space%' OR description LIKE '%space%')");
$this->db->limit($aLimit, $aOffset);   

$this->db->select('id,description,title,fee');

$query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);
```

Haven't tested it but it should get you on the way.  Other than that I don't think it's possible to include a grouped/bracketed query any other way.

Comment: if I use the sql statement, do I need to escape the word or it will help me escape automatically?

Comment: A quick test suggests that the search words are not escaped.

Answer (score 1):

**Grouping LIKE clause (putting parenthesis around)**

```
$this->db->group_start();
$this->db->like('name', $query_array['q']);
$this->db->or_like('description', $query_array['q']);
$this->db->group_end();
```

**Will produce round backets like this**

```
 (
   `name` LIKE '%test%' ESCAPE '!' 
    OR  `description` LIKE '%test%' ESCAPE '!' 
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just do something like

```
$this->db->where('status', $aStatus);     
$this->db->limit($aLimit, $aOffset);   

$this->db->where(sprintf(
    '(title LIKE %s OR description LIKE %s)',
    $this->db->escape_like_str($aString),    
    $this->db->escape_like_str($aString)
), NULL);    

$this->db->select('id,description,title,fee');

$query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);
```